# 'firebase project:list' cli command Displays Projects from Another Account Even When Logged Out; Unable to Access Projects of Logged-In Account

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-tools

as mentioned in the title, I have different project on firebase with different emails, when I try configure flutter project using firebase cli, I get projects from another account.

The command that I'm running :

1. `firebase logout` : logout from current account
2. `firebase login`  : login to the account that contains the desired project
3. `firebase init`   : in order to config the current project this will show the message in the image below
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgJVK.png)
   when I click on yes, and choose the services that I want to use with spaceBar and go to next step, it will show a list (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJqyC.png).
   When I choose 'Use an existing project' it will show projects from another account.
   does anyone faced the same problem ? how it's solved and thank you.
   if my description is not clear, please let a comment and i will do my best to do it better than that.